# Where does it create the 7zip compressed files

Tags: windows, 7zip

I am using "7-zip 9.20" on "Windows 7".

If I compress a file in my "C" drive (ex: c:\myFolder ), using 7-zip, the output will be creating somewhere else. At this time, I cant find it even with a windows file search.

Does anyone know, where the default location and how can I change it...?

Comment: I think you're better off asking this at superuser.com, as this type of question doesn't really belong _here_.

Comment: I think could be failing silently, because normally it should popup an ACL-question where you need to confirm your rights to write straight to c:\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the default location. This may be useful for some other as well.

C:\Users{user_name}\AppData\Local\VirtualStore

Answer (score 3):

For anyone with this issue still using Windows 7, but updated to 7-Zip version of 16.04.

If you select the folder to archive >> Tools >> Options >> Folders tab, it will show the options for the Working Folder: System temp folder, current, or Specified, the last of which allows you to designate a path directory for every time you compress the file.

Comment: Thank you!  This is still true as of version 18.06.

Comment: FYI use %temp% to get to the temp folder. when you archive it shows you part of the name so I'm not sure how useful this is as you can't fully locate the zipped folder. still works for version 23.01

Answer (score 0):

I thought the default was to the folder containing the files you try to archive.

When you select "Add to archive" there is a `...` button beside the Archive name, where you can browse to the location you require.

Comment: Unfortunately this special issue raised only when the file is in 'c:\' (protected system file locations). For other locations, it will be working as you mentioned.
it may be due to the security restrictions comes with windows..